# Should questions with a score -10 or worse be deleted?

Tags: discussion, deletion

Currently, $3$ questions on math stack exchange have a score -10 or worse, bot are not yet deleted.

> Should questions with a score of -10 or worse be deleted ? Or even automatically deleted ?

A question with a score -10 or worse will usually be a low-quality question, so should such questions be deleted ?

Does an automatic deletion of such question make sense ? I am curious what the MSE-users think about this.

Comment: I'd like to think that only deletion-worthy questions make it to -10, but I'm concerned that an automatic deletion policy would be somewhat easily manipulable by a group of voters. I don't think this is a very big issue, though - there are so few questions that make it to -10 or below without deletion votes.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2892042/174736) will be automatically deleted by Roomba next week, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2887777/174736) won't be because it's answered.

Comment: @AndrewT. [It's deleted now](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887777/proof-check-is-there-a-flaw)